# Android ConstraintSet all views have same horizontal bias

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using a ConstraintSet to constrain two views in my app. The Constraints get created properly, but when i want to set the horizontal bias, it sets it for all views in my ConstraintLayout. Here is my Code:

```
cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);

//here is the problem, because in the end the bias is 0.026F for both views.
cs.setHorizontalBias(text.getId(), 0.9F);
cs.setHorizontalBias(img.getId(), 0.026F);

cs.applyTo(cl);
```

Is this a known bug, or am I doing anything wrong? I read the docs and it says that it should set it for the given view:

```
"Adjust the horizontal bias of the view (used with views constrained on left and right)."
```

What should i do?

Comment: Make sure that you have unique ids for the two views.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have something else wrong, I have just tested your code and it works fine. The text is set to the right and the image to the left.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContaintLayoutActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Este es un texto de prueba para este view"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class ContaintLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConstraintLayout cl;
    ImageView img;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.constraint_with_progress);

        cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.clConstraintLayout);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);

        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
        cs.clone(cl);

        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);

        cs.setHorizontalBias(text.getId(), 0.9F);
        cs.setHorizontalBias(img.getId(), 0.026F);

        cs.applyTo(cl);
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT I**

When adding views programatically as stated in comments, the most likely problem you are facing is not setting an id for the view, in which case both are set to -1, hence the both get the same constraints when you call *.getId();

This is the way I made it work:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContaintLayoutActivity">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ids for the views in res/values/ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="ivImage" type="id"/>
    <item name="tvText" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Activity:

```
public class ContaintLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConstraintLayout cl;
    ImageView img;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.constraint_with_progress);

        cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.clConstraintLayout);

        img = new ImageView(this);
        img.setId(R.id.ivImage);
        img.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon_blue));
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("A text for testing");
        text.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setId(R.id.tvText);

        cl.addView(img);
        cl.addView(text);


        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
        cs.clone(cl);

        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
        cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 8);
        cs.connect(text.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);


        cs.setHorizontalBias(text.getId(), 0.9F);
        cs.setHorizontalBias(img.getId(), 0.026F);

        cs.applyTo(cl);

        cl.invalidate(); // May not be necessary
    }
```

Comment: Is it relevant here, that i am Creating the Elements in code too? `ConstraintLayout cl = new ConstraintLayout(this.activity);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this.activity);
        TextView text = new TextView(this.activity);`

Comment: Check the EDIT I to the answer

Comment: Yeah. I just fixed that problem and now everything works fine! Thanks!